# Where did all the weapons come from?

Tags: hot-fuzz

In Hot Fuzz, they find a giant weapons cache at this old man's house.  I remember him saying something about he "found" them.  Do we have any idea where they came from?  If not, was this supposed to be a nod and a wink at some type of trope?

Comment: you mean that place where they get that huge looking bomb from?

Comment: Don't remember it that well, but I would think it was not to be answered where he found them. It was just meant to be funny having this old guy with a garage full of weapons he just *"found"* somewhere for you to make your own explanation out of it (maybe he really found them, which would be quite odd/funny on its own, maybe he was actively accumulating them which would make him quite suspicious). It was probably in the same sense of this superficially idyllic village with its dark (in the end very dark) hidden corners that was a theme of the whole movie.

Comment: The exact explanation is "Found 'em". As for the preceding shots of the weapons, that is definitely a take on previous action flicks which have highlighted the arms at hand - see Commando, Aliens etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is meant as a satire of other action films where people simply seem to have access to special force style weapon caches.

The joke ("Found 'em") makes you think about where on earth all of these guns and a sea mine could possibly have come from and how the old man could have obtained them.

Comment: Especially as this is set in the UK where most guns are illegal